# RestTemplate: While calling an API from one localhost to another i get error

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I am working on spring boot project. In my eclipse I run two project first one is `flight_system` and second one is `travel-site`. I am sending request from `travel-site` to flight_system for get `booking` but i am getting error in postman. Url for get booking in `flight_system` is `localhost:8050/booking` which is work correctly in postman. Url for get booking in `travel-site` is `localhost:8051/travel-site/booking` which produce error in postman.

##### Here down is my code of `flight_system`:

*Entity*

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    private String bookingId;
    private String passangerName;
    private String flightName;
    private String source;
    private String destination;

    // getter setter constructor
}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class BookingController {

    @Autowired
    private BookingService bookingService;

    @GetMapping("/booking")
    public List<Booking> getBooking() {
        return bookingService.getAllBooking();
    }
}
```

##### Here down is my code of `travel-site`:

*Model*

```
public class Booking {

    private String bookingId;
    private String passangerName;
    private String flightName;
    private String source;
    private String destination;

    // getter setter constructor
}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class TravelSiteController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8050/";

    @GetMapping(value = "/travel-site/booking")
    public Booking getBooking() {

        ResponseEntity<Booking> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + "booking", HttpMethod.GET, null,
                Booking.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

*Stack trace in postman*

> "message": "Error while extracting response for type [class com.travelsite.model.Booking] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.travelsite.model.Booking` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.travelsite.model.Booking` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 ResponseEntity<Booking> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + "booking", HttpMethod.GET, null,
                Booking.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
```

to

```
List<Booking> booking = restTemplate
  .getForObject(baseUrl + "booking",List.class);
```

To know better about rest template method you can go through this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

Comment: I get same error. After changing this

Comment: Much thanks bro. I'm stuck from one day.

Comment: check my new answer. I edited

Comment: Can you learn me in detail in your answer why this error is coming?

Comment: From first microservice you are returning `List<Booking>` but on second microservice you are receiving only `Booking`. That's why you were getting error.